# How to copy a visual studio project to another directory without issues with file paths and errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-project

I want to copy a project without having issuing with file paths and the code seeing another project of the same code and as a result Bugging out

So can i do this in a simple way?

Comment: Copy the entire folder to a new location.  The issue is usually the csproj file which is text.  I usually edit the csproj file so the paths are relative instead of absolute.  Then when you copy the new project doesn't affect the old copy.

Comment: @jdweng ok but how do you edit the csproj file without opening it or do i HAVE to open it??

Comment: A .csproj file is just a text file. Just make sure you have a backup before you edit it, or use source control (stronlgly advised!)

Comment: You just have to edit once to remove the relative paths.  Then you can copy it as many times as you like.  I usually make backup copies of my project every day.  So I do it once and then copy the entire project folder for backup daily.

Comment: @jdweng and stuartd , Thanks for all your help you guys are the best and it didn't corrupt my Original file YAY!!!.

Comment: @jdweng . All i had to do is copy the file in another folder and change the csproj file name and open it and then when i close it asks to create a vs project for it so Thanks dude :)

Comment: Did you check to see in the csproj the files are referencing the new folder or the old folder?